# Cutting Plane using Java

Tags: optimization, cplex

I am working in my project using Java with Cplex library. But I'm stuck at applying cuttting plane. Is there any tutorial or article for that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples included with CPLEX when you install CPLEX Optimization Studio (COS). For example, if `COSDIR` is the location where you installed the product, then the examples can be found at `COSDIR/cplex/examples/src/java`. In particular, you should look at the `AdMIPex4.java` and `AdMIPex8.java` examples. See the documentation for the new [generic callbacks](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/callbacks/introCallbacks.html) in CPLEX 12.8 or the [legacy callbacks](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/callbacks_basic/01_cb_title_synopsis.html).